# PHP - foreach key always returns zero

Tags: php

Trying to update and delete records from a database but my $key always returns zero.  Here is my code.  Please let me know if I need to clarify anything.  Thank you.

Please note, I did not include the select statement for the "while" below.

```
        // Fetch rows:      
    while ($Row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result5)) {

        $id = $Row['id'];
        $notes = $Row['RejectedNotes'];
        $first = $Row['FIRST'];
        $last = $Row['LAST'];
        $ssn = $Row['SSN'];
        $psn = $Row['PSN'];
        $dob = $Row['DOB'];
        $distdocket = $Row['DistDocket'];
        $releasedate = $Row['ReleaseDate'];
        $releasetype = $Row['ReleaseType'];

        $columnData4 =  "<table class='footerTable'><tr><td class='footerFirst'>"
        . $first .              "</td><td class='footerLast'>"
        . $last .               "</td><td class='footerSSN'>"
        . $ssn .                "</td><td><input type='text' class='footerNMCD' name = 'psn[]' value = '"
        . $psn .                "'></td><td class='footerDOB'>"
        . $dob .                "</td><td class='footerCause'>"
        . $distdocket .         "</td><td><input type='text' class='footerRelease' name = 'releasedate[]' value = '"
        . $releasedate .        "'></td><td>"
        .                       "<select name='relOptions[]' id='releaseOptions' class='footerEvent'>"
        .                       "<option value='$releasetype'>$releasetype</option>"
        .                       "<option value='Discharge'>Discharge</option>"
        .                       "<option value='In-House Parole'>In-House Parole</option>"
        .                       "</select></td>"
        .                       "<td class='reason'>"
        .                       "<button class='reason' onclick='openNotesBox(\"$notes\");'>View</button></td><td>"
        .                       "<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value=\"$id\" />$id</td></tr>";
        print $columnData4; 
    }
    print "</form></table>";


                // I know this is strange code, but it's what I had to do for Chrome.
    if(isset($_REQUEST['resubmit']) || isset($_REQUEST['remove']))
    {                   
        $checkbox=$_POST['checkbox'];               
        $nmcd=$_POST['psn'];
        $release=$_POST['releasedate'];
        $relOptions=$_POST['relOptions'];                           
        //HERE IS MY ISSUE!!!  $key is always "0".  
        foreach ($checkbox as $key => $value)
        {
            $nmcd = $nmcd[$key];
            $release = $release[$key];
            $releasedate = substr($release, 0, 2) . "-" . substr($release, 2, 2) . "-" . substr($release, 4, 4);
            $relOptions = $relOptions[$key];


            if(isset($_REQUEST['remove']))
            {           
                $del = "DELETE FROM submitted WHERE id='$value'";
                $result = mssql_query($del);
            }
            else {  
                if(isset($_REQUEST['resubmit']))
                {
                    $resub = "UPDATE submitted 
                             SET PSN = '$nmcd', ReleaseDate='$releasedate', ReleaseType='$relOptions', Rejected='0'
                             where id='$value'";
                    $result = mssql_query($resub);
                }           
            }       
        }
    }
```

Comment: try  print_r($_POST["checkbox"]) to see what keys are you getting in first place

Comment: Off topic, but if the "View" button isn't your submit button you should make it `<button type="button"` because by default it's `type="submit"` in Chrome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Checkbox group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889913/php-checkbox-group)

Comment: Hanky Panky, thanks for your response.  I am getting 0.  If I check more than one checkbox, I get 0, 1, 2, but if I check (say) the third box down, I am getting 0.  I am very weak with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the `$value` of the checkbox, not the `$key`. Your code reads:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value=\"$id\" />$id</td>
```

In which you specify *no index value* for the `checkbox[]` array, so all values will be added in the order they are set. As @ilmari-karonen noted with the comment referencing [PHP - Checkbox group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889913/php-checkbox-group), you must specify a meaningful value in the HTML if you wish to receive it back in the form data. ie:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[$some_index]' value=\"$id\" />$id</td>
```

Comment: Thank you Sammitch (cute name).  That got me closer.  I used the $id as the index and it is now updating the correct database item, however, it's loading the fields with blanks instead of the changes.  Any ideas?  Thank you, again.

Comment: Sammitch!  You are a genius!  Thank you.  I just needed to add that same index to the rest of my array items and it works!  I've been stuck with this thing for days!  Thanks a million!