# $_POST for checkbox

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

I have this form and its details need to be send in an email. As of now I have only managed to do the other fields to be included in the email but I am having a trouble with this multiple checkboxes. I have lots of checkboxes, 23 to be exact. Now, the problem I am encountering is, how will I include the value of the checkbox if one checkbox is checked or just two or three checkboxes are checked.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="state" id="txt1">State:</input>
<input type="text" name="name" id="txt2">Name:</input>
Package A<input type="checkbox" name="radiog_dark" value="150.00" id="tcbx3" class="css-checkbox"/>
Package B<input type="checkbox" name="radiog_dark" value="175.00" id="tcbx3" class="css-checkbox"/>
Package C<input type="checkbox" name="radiog_dark" value="200.00" id="tcbx3" class="css-checkbox"/>
```

**PHP**

```
$state = $_POST['state'];
$entity = $_POST['entity'];

$email_message .= "State: ".clean_string($state)."\n";
$email_message .= "Entity: ".clean_string($entity)."\n";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Checkbox group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889913/php-checkbox-group)

Answer (score 0):

Use isset() method to check for the checkbox is checked or not

```
if(isset($_POST['radiog_dark'])){
// do something
}
```

Further more you cant have same names for two checkboxes as you will get only one, other 2 will over that one

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array` Syntax to set your checkbox field like this way and check your checkbox value using `isset`, you can set the array index like this way to more readablity e.g

```
name="radiog_dark['package_a']"
name="radiog_dark['package_b']"
```

`<input type="checkbox" name="radiog_dark[]" value="150.00" id="tcbx3" class="css-checkbox"/>`

```
if(isset($_POST['radiog_dark'])){
  // do other stuffs
 }
```

Comment: i was hoping to have an output like this: Package Selected: Package A - 150.00

Comment: then use array key index like radiog_dark['Package A'] on your name attribute of checkbox input

Answer (score 0):

```
change chekbox name  radiog_dark to radiog_dark[] 

Package A<input type="checkbox" name="radiog_dark[]" value="150.00" id="tcbx3" class="css-checkbox"/>

if(!empty($_POST['radiog_dark'])){
    // Loop to store  display values of individual checked checkbox.
    foreach($_POST['radiog_dark'] as $selected){
    echo $selected."</br>";
}
```

Comment: i was hoping to have an output like this: Package Selected: Package A - 150.00