# Dynamically generated inputs not showing up in my request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have something like this

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" 
name="itemform" id="itemform" action="{{ url('/item/save') }}">

@foreach($items as $item)
<input type="checkbox" name="MyItems[]" value="{{$item->id}}">
@endforeach
</form>
            <button  type="submit" form="itemform">Save</button>
```

Then I submit it and do this:

```
public function my_items(Request $request){
dd($request);
}
```

This show me an object that conaints:

request -> parameters -> MyItem

MyItem is an Array that only contains the value of the first `$item->id`, no matter if I check the entire list. I expect it to give me a list of `$item->id` that I have checked on the form. Any help?

Comment: try dd(request->all()); and show result pls.

Comment: @VaheGalstyan Did that. The result is the same as described, only the first id and only if it is checked.

Comment: I think this is the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889913/php-checkbox-group

Comment: @VaheGalstyan I already saw that one, however I have other form somewhere else that uses this same syntax (name="item[]" and works fine. I don't know why this one doesn't and I'd like to know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following replace in your code line like this
`<input type="checkbox" name="MyItems[{{$item->id}}]" value="{{$item->id}}">` or use for and use iterator instead $item->id;

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this:

```
public function my_items(Request $request){

 print_r($request->all());
  exit;
}
```

This will print the all post, may this help you to find the value from post.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this code

```
public function my_items(Request $request){
   dd($request->all());
}
```